# How to store data in text file in java

Tags: java, file-io

How to store data in text file in java that has various attributes like name, author etc that will be inputted by the user on CLI.
any Idea?

Thanks

Comment: Please post an exapmple of the text file format.

Comment: As mentioned - without an example of data structure you want to persist in text file, there will be no precise answer. I could give you at least 5 different responses from the hat.

Comment: this is not specific enough to be a good question. Please paste an example piece of code on how you have done this so far.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the Java class that will suit you best is a [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html). However, if you are writing a file with Key=Value lines, then the [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class might end up being the better choice.

Answer (score 1):

"[S]tore data in text file" sounds like you want a readable format. You can use comma-separated value (CSV) files.

You can write your own CSV serializer (search on SO for "how to write csv java") or use a solution like the [Java CSV library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacsv/).

Answer (score 1):

Use DataOutputStream and DataInputStream. Using this class make it easier to read integer, float, double data and others without needing to interpret if the read data should be an integer or a float data.

something lyk dis

DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);

```
        //
        // Below we write some data to the cities.dat.
        // DataOutputStream class have various method that allow
        // us to write primitive type data and string. There are
        // method called writeInt(), writeFloat(), writeUTF(),
        // etc.
        //
        dos.writeInt(cityIdA);
        dos.writeUTF(cityNameA);
        dos.writeInt(cityPopulationA);
        dos.writeFloat(cityTempA);

        dos.writeInt(cityIdB);
        dos.writeUTF(cityNameB);
        dos.writeInt(cityPopulationB);
        dos.writeFloat(cityTempB);

        dos.flush();
        dos.close();
```

Comment: Writes binary data, but "text file" in the OPs question indicates something readable.

Comment: It has methods to write readable characters too..@Matten hv a look...http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/network/prirucky/javatut/java/io/dataIO.html

Comment: nice to know, looks like an easy way to implement a csv reader with \t as separation character and a fixed format :) +1